# Replicate simulations and For Loop in R

Tags: r

Hi guys sorry I’m a total beginner in R.

I have an Excel table:

```
Fund count
1 1961
2 2086
3 453
...
```

What I’m trying to do is: For each fund I would like to run 1000 simulations where I draw random numbers from range `1001:24999` as many times as the `count` for that fund. Then, work out how many random numbers are less than 6000. Last, obtain the average across the 1000 simulations.

After importing the file into RStudio, I have written so far:

```
#count for the first fund in the table
z <- replicate(1000, {1001:24449, replace=T, size=1961})
count<-length(which(z>6000))
mean(count)
```

I seem to be able to use the above for one fund and I know Im supposed to use a for loop for all funds.

I’m completely novice any feedback would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

For every `count` value in your `data.frame`, draw as many samples from `1001:24999` with replacement, and return the number of sampled values that are < 6000; repeat `Nsim = 1000` times.

```
Nsim <- 1000
lst <- replicate(Nsim, lapply(
    apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(1001:24999, x["count"], replace = T)),
    function(x) sum(x < 6000)))
```

Store in `matrix` with `Nsim` columns and as many rows as there are rows in your original `data.frame`.

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(lst), ncol = Nsim)
```

Calculate the mean for every row.

```
rowMeans(mat)
#[1] 409.215 433.868  93.973
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Fund count
1 1961
2 2086
3 453", header = T)
```

Comment: You're very welcome @user11370994; please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for future users to identify relevant questions. It also offers a small reputation bonus to both the original poster and respondent.